# angular component test for events

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-unittest

I have a custom component and try to test for the emitted events

My component looks like this:

```dart
@Component(
  selector: "my-component",
  templateUrl: 'component/my-component.html',
  useShadowDom: false,
  publishAs: "ctrl"
)

class MyComponent implements ScopeAware {
  Scope scope;

  String value = "foo"

  void onButtonClick(){
    scope.emit('on-select', value);
  }
}
```

The component emits a 'on-select' event when a button is clicked. Works like expected but since i'm a huge fan of testing i want to test for that event.

Is this possible in angular 0.14.0?

I write my tests like the tests in [angulardart-sample-app](https://github.com/vsavkin/angulardart-sample-app)

The whole component testing has really a lot of boilerplate and is everything else then fun to write. Are there simpler ways for component testing in 0.14.0 or the future?